# Reduce RAM Usage for AlexNet implementation on FPGA

Tags: python, neural-network, fpga, xilinx

I am working on an intelligent embedded system that implemented with an alexnet (kind of shallow cnn) while training my model on colab, I realized that RAM usage is about 10 GB. Does FPGA Support this? How can I reduce RAM usage?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no FPGAs with 10 GB of RAM built-in, but many of them will let you connect that much RAM externally.